# Replace space character at the end of a line with a specific string

Tags: linux, sed, awk, whitespace, replace

I'm dealing with space delimited file with 6 fields:

```
Pop1 ID60776 62 C 10 62
Pop1 ID62442 13 A 2 13
Pop1 ID63614 56 C 0 
Pop1 ID67511 61 T 37 61
Pop1 ID68222 51 A 0 
Pop1 ID68407 65 C 16 65
```

However, in lines 3 and 5, there are only 5 fields. In these cases, the 0 in field 5 is followed by a space character ('0 ').

I would like to find all instances of a space character at the end of a line (i.e. \s$ ) and replace it with space NA (i.e. '\sNA') but I am having real trouble doing so. For example, I have tried sed:

```
sed s/\\s$/\\sNA/g
```

but it's not working. Can someone help me out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a couple of equivalent solutions in `awk`:

```
awk '{ printf("%s", $0) } NF == 5 { printf("NA") } { printf("\n") }
```

and

```
awk '{ print $0 (NF==5 ? "NA" : "") }'
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `\s` can't be used in the replacement string since it is a class.
2. The `$` is probably being interpreted by the shell.

Try:

```
sed -e's/\s$/ NA/'
```

Comment: Hi Douglas, thank you for the prompt reply! I have tried typing the space character in this way, but I get the error:

    sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unterminated `s' command

Comment: Apologies! This does work - I was calling the command through another programme and not using the single quotes. My Windows habits are hard to break!

Answer (score 2):

Put a real space instead of \s, and use single quote (`'`) to avoid the shell to perform variable substitution:

```
sed -e 's/ $/ NA/'
```

Comment: Thank you jfgagne. The single quotes fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in pure bash shell, avoiding to start a sed or awk process:

```
while read line; do
  printf "%s" "$line"
  nbchar=${#line}
  if [ ${line:$((nbchar-1))} == " " ] ; then printf "NA"; fi
  printf "\n"
done < your_file
```

Comment: This may be a bit simpler: `case "$line" in (*" ") echo "${line}NA" ;; (*) echo "$line" ;; esac`